# Callback function from child to parent component in React

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to make a chat. But when I send a message I need to refresh page to get data on the page. I have to components Forms and SendMsg.

Parent:

```
...
import client from '../Utils/Contentful';

export default class Forms extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            messages: [],
        }
    } 

    componentDidMount(){
        client.getEntries({limit:300, order: 'sys.createdAt', content_type:'nameTest'}).then(response => {
            this.setState({messages: response.items});
        }).catch(e => {
          console.log(e);
        });
    }
render() {
        return (
            <div className="chat">
                <div className="container-xl">
                    <MessageList messages={this.state.messages}/>
                    <SendMsg />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

And child component

```
...
import client from '../Utils/ContentfulCM';

export default class SendMsg extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            message:'',
            userEmail:'ddd@gmail.com',
            chatName:'ggg'
        }
        this.sendMessage = this.sendMessage.bind(this)
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)

    } 

    handleChange(e) {
        this.setState({
            message: e.target.value,
        })
    }

    sendMessage(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        const form = e.target;
        const data = new FormData(form);

        client.getSpace(client.space)
        .then((space) => space.getEnvironment('master'))
        .then((environment) => environment.createEntry('nameTest', {
            fields: {
                chatName: {
                    'en-US': data.get('chatName')
                },
                //... some data
            }
        }))
        .then((entry) => entry.publish())
        .catch(console.error)

        this.setState({
            message: ''
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="send-message">
                <Form className="send-msg" onSubmit={this.sendMessage}>
                    <FormGroup>
                        <Input type="hidden" name="userEmail" value={this.state.userEmail}/>    
                    </FormGroup>
                    <FormGroup>
                        <Input type="hidden" name="chatName" value={this.state.chatName}/>    
                    </FormGroup>

                    <FormGroup>
                        <Input 
                            type="text" 
                            name="text"
                            onChange={this.handleChange}
                            value={this.state.message}
                            placeholder="Write your message here"
                            required />
                    </FormGroup>
                    <FormGroup>
                        <Input type="hidden" name="dateCreated" value={moment().format()} onChange={this.handleChange}/>    
                    </FormGroup>
                </Form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I try to add props but not sure about right place for them
Any suggestions?

### Update 1

Both components have "import client" (they are different because have uniq accessToken), that's why I can't use them in one component.

### Update 2

I've change question according to suggestion below, but still need to refresh page in order to get displayed data.

Parent:

```
export default class Forms extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            messages: [],
        }
        this.sendMessage = this.sendMessage.bind(this);
    } 

    componentDidMount(){
        client1.getEntries({limit:300, order: 'sys.createdAt', content_type:'nameTest'}).then(response => {
            this.setState({messages: response.items});
        }).catch(e => {
          console.log(e);
        });
    }
sendMessage(data) {
        client2.getSpace(client2.space)
        .then((space) => space.getEnvironment('master'))
        .then((environment) => environment.createEntry('nameTest', {
            fields: {
                chatName: {
                    'en-US': data.get('chatName')
                ... some data
            }
        }))
        .then((entry) => entry.publish())
        .catch(console.error)
    }
render() {
        return (
            <div className="chat">
                <div className="container-xl">
                    <MessageList messages={this.state.messages}/>
                    <SendMsg onSendMessage={this.sendMessage}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

And child component

```
export default class SendMsg extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            message:'',
            userEmail:'ddd@gmail.com',
            chatName:'ggg'
        }
        this.sendMessage = this.sendMessage.bind(this)
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)

    } 

    handleChange(e) {
        this.setState({
            message: e.target.value,
        })
    }

    sendMessage(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        const { onSendMessage } = this.props;

        const form = e.target;
        const data = new FormData(form);

        // if send message handler was passed, invoke with form data
        onSendMessage && onSendMessage(data);

        this.setState({
            message: ''
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="send-message">
                <Form className="send-msg" onSubmit={this.sendMessage}>
                    <FormGroup>
                        <Input type="hidden" name="userEmail" value={this.state.userEmail}/>    
                    </FormGroup>
                    <FormGroup>
                        <Input type="hidden" name="chatName" value={this.state.chatName}/>    
                    </FormGroup>

                    <FormGroup>
                        <Input 
                            type="text" 
                            name="text"
                            onChange={this.handleChange}
                            value={this.state.message}
                            placeholder="Write your message here"
                            required />
                    </FormGroup>
                    <FormGroup>
                        <Input type="hidden" name="dateCreated" value={moment().format()} onChange={this.handleChange}/>    
                    </FormGroup>
                </Form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `client` in both components? Where is it sending the messages in the child? You need to use the [react component lifecycle functions](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle) to react to state/props updating (or external updates).

Comment: it's different client. One with key for display info another for manage it (according to Contentful). The function sendMessage(e) responsible for sending. I tried to use props but do not understand completely where how to put it

Comment: Are you sure the access tokens are different? This parent-child component code runs at the same time, on the same page, in the same app, in the same environment, so the `REACT_APP_CONTENTFUL_CMA_ACCESS_TOKEN` env variable *would have to be the same*. When you say "send chat" are you referring to 2 *actual* client apps conversing, where one is sending a message to the other, and the receiving app needs to reload the page to see latest?

Comment: just checked it twice ... it does not work. Either does not show data or does not send :(

Comment: I suspect you need to implement the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle function so your component can respond to state updates, **and/or** implement the client receiver that gets message updates in order to update state in the parent component and instantiate that in `componentDidMount`. A 100% completely different issue than this question regarding the callbacks.

Comment: I've change import to these: import client1 from '../Utils/Contentful';
import client2 from '../Utils/ContentfulCM'; and added to your solution. It works like before ... still need page refreshing

Comment: It looks like the question now incorporates the suggestions made in an answer below, and we do not do that here. This is because the question had invalidated the answer, and future readers will not understand the answer in the context of the question now. They may even downvote it as it appears to be wrong or irrelevant. I suggest we roll back your question to the original state, and then show the changes you made in an update.

Comment: Updated my answer to include a way to periodically sync messages. It appears that `contentful` won't "push" out updates so your code needs to check for them.

Answer (score 2):

Define the callback in the parent. Split out the logic of sending the message data from extracting it from the form in the child. The parent's callback receives the message data and sends it, while the child component's function pulls the form data, formats it, calls the callback passed in props, and clears the input field.

parent

```
export default class Forms extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            messages: [],
        }
        this.sendMessage = this.sendMessage.bind(this);
    } 

    componentDidMount(){
        client.getEntries({limit:300, order: 'sys.createdAt', content_type:'nameTest'}).then(response => {
            this.setState({messages: response.items});
        }).catch(e => {
          console.log(e);
        });
    }

    sendMessage(data) {
        client.getSpace(client.space)
        .then((space) => space.getEnvironment('master'))
        .then((environment) => environment.createEntry('nameTest', {
            fields: {
                chatName: {
                    'en-US': data.get('chatName')
                },
                //... some data
            }
        }))
        .then((entry) => entry.publish())
        .catch(console.error);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="chat">
                <div className="container-xl">
                    <MessageList messages={this.state.messages}/>
                    <SendMsg onSendMessage={sendMessage} />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

child

```
export default class SendMsg extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            message:'',
            userEmail:'ddd@gmail.com',
            chatName:'ggg'
        }
        this.sendMessage = this.sendMessage.bind(this)
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)

    } 

    handleChange(e) {
        this.setState({
            message: e.target.value,
        })
    }

    sendMessage(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        const { onSendMessage } = this.props;

        const form = e.target;
        const data = new FormData(form);

        // if send message handler was passed, invoke with form data
        onSendMessage && onSendMessage(data);

        this.setState({
            message: ''
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="send-message">
                <Form className="send-msg" onSubmit={this.sendMessage}>
                    <FormGroup>
                        <Input type="hidden" name="userEmail" value={this.state.userEmail}/>    
                    </FormGroup>
                    <FormGroup>
                        <Input type="hidden" name="chatName" value={this.state.chatName}/>    
                    </FormGroup>

                    <FormGroup>
                        <Input 
                            type="text" 
                            name="text"
                            onChange={this.handleChange}
                            value={this.state.message}
                            placeholder="Write your message here"
                            required />
                    </FormGroup>
                    <FormGroup>
                        <Input type="hidden" name="dateCreated" value={moment().format()} onChange={this.handleChange}/>    
                    </FormGroup>
                </Form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**UPDATE** to include syncing capability

[Sync API](https://contentful.github.io/contentful.js/contentful/4.5.0/ContentfulClientAPI.html#.sync)

[Using the Sync API with Javascirpt](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/javascript/tutorials/using-the-sync-api-with-js/)

Updates to parent component:

- Add a class instance timer variable to hold interval timer reference
- Create functions to handle syncing data calls
- Update `componentDidMount` to sync initial data when the component mounts, and setup data synchronization polling (*since this isn't event driven*)
- Add timer cleanup in `componentWillUnmount` lifecycle function

Parent

```
constructor() {
  super()
  this.state = {
    messages: [],
  }
  this.syncTimer = null;

  this.sendMessage = this.sendMessage.bind(this);
}

initialSyncClient = () => client1.sync({
  initial: true
  limit:100,
  order: 'sys.createdAt',
  content_type: 'nameTest',
});

syncClient = () => {
  const { nextSyncToken } = this.state;
  client1.sync({
    nextSyncToken
  })
    .then(this.handleSyncResponse)
    .catch(e => {
      console.log(e);
    });
};

handleSyncResponse = ({ entries, nextSyncToken}) => {
  // response shape is a little different, 
  // response.entries vs. response.items, so need to access correctly
  // also need to save nextSyncToken for all subsequent syncs
  this.setState({
    messages: entries.items,
    nextSyncToken,
  });
};

componentDidMount(){
  // do initial sync
  this.initialSyncClient()
    .then(this.handleSyncResponse)
    .catch(e => {
      console.log(e);
    });

  // setup sync polling, 15 second interval
  this.syncTimer = setInterval(syncClient, 15 * 1000);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  // clean up polling timer when component unmounts
  clearInterval(this.syncTimer);
}
```

*NOTE:* These changes based purely on the `contentful` documentation, so there may be need of some tweaking to get working as expected, or if you prefer *not* using arrow functions, etc...

Comment: Thanks Drew. But I can't use client in one file (they have different key).

Comment: @Vova So using a callback won't work then? The same parent component is rendering both components, and thus, both "client" objects, now. So then the question becomes, how to do that *within the same component* I guess.

Comment: I tried to make something like that import {client as client2} from '../Utils/ContentfulCM'; but get error "Attempted import error: 'client' is not exported from '../Utils/ContentfulCM' (imported as 'client2').

Comment: @Vova How is `client` imported now? Default export?

Comment: Yes, default. -> export default contentful.createClient({
    space: process.env.REACT_APP_CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID,
    accessToken: process.env.REACT_APP_CONTENTFUL_CMA_ACCESS_TOKEN
});

Comment: they work in different files ... but doesn't in one

Comment: @Vova I don't understand, it's the same object imported in both cases. Is there some other piece of initialization that is different in both? Please update your question with these further details. Using callbacks (working or not) may not be the issue here then.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210639/discussion-between-vova-and-drew-reese).

Answer (score 0):

i don't see where you try to add function sendMessage to parent.

You can provide it by props, why not.

in child component, you can do something like this

```
interface IChildComponentWithSendMessage{
    sendMessage
}

export class ChildComponent extends React.Component<IChildComponentWithSendMessage>
```

and you can provide you messageMethod by props

also you don't have to do

```
   this.sendMessage = this.sendMessage.bind(this)
```

also i thinkt that could be your problem why you can't provide this method to child/parent component

you can create functions like this:

```
sendMessage = () => {
}
```