# Add data to the page without refreshing it in React

Tags: reactjs

I've posted this question earlier, but probably not quite clearly formulated it. I have a chat. When I add message it goes to database but not updated on page. So I need it to be updated on page after adding a msg.

Parent component Forms

```
export default class Forms extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            messages: [],
        }
        this.sendMessage = this.sendMessage.bind(this);
    } 

    componentDidMount(){
        client1.getEntries({limit:300, order: 'sys.createdAt', 
     content_type:'nameTest'}).then(response => {
            this.setState({messages: response.items});
        }).catch(e => {
          console.log(e);
        });
    }
    sendMessage(data) {
        client2.getSpace(client2.space)
        .then((space) => space.getEnvironment('master'))
        .then((environment) => environment.createEntry('nameTest', {
            fields: {
                chatName: {
                    'en-US': data.get('chatName')
                ... some data
            }
        }))
        .then((entry) => entry.publish())
        .catch(console.error)
    }
render() {
        return (
            <div className="chat">
                <div className="container-xl">
                    <MessageList messages={this.state.messages}/>
                    <SendMsg onSendMessage={this.sendMessage}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

the child component SengMsg

```
export default class SendMsg extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            message:'',
            userEmail:'ddd@gmail.com',
            chatName:'ggg'
        }
        this.sendMessage = this.sendMessage.bind(this)
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)

    } 

    handleChange(e) {
        this.setState({
            message: e.target.value,
        })
    }

    sendMessage(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        const { onSendMessage } = this.props;

        const form = e.target;
        const data = new FormData(form);

        // if send message handler was passed, invoke with form data
        onSendMessage && onSendMessage(data);

        this.setState({
            message: ''
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="send-message">
                <Form className="send-msg" onSubmit={this.sendMessage}>
                    <FormGroup>
                        <Input type="hidden" name="userEmail" value={this.state.userEmail}/>    
                    </FormGroup>
                    <FormGroup>
                        <Input type="hidden" name="chatName" value={this.state.chatName}/>    
                    </FormGroup>

                    <FormGroup>
                        <Input 
                            type="text" 
                            name="text"
                            onChange={this.handleChange}
                            value={this.state.message}
                            placeholder="Write your message here"
                            required />
                    </FormGroup>
                    <FormGroup>
                        <Input type="hidden" name="dateCreated" value={moment().format()} onChange={this.handleChange}/>    
                    </FormGroup>
                </Form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I only see a call to `this.setState({messages: response.items});` in the parent when the component loads, you need to update it at some interval, specially after a message is sent since you know a new message needs to display.

Comment: Do you mean setInterval? But if I add setInterval does it mean that the page will constantly update ... even nothing happen on page?

Comment: First you need to call `this.setState({messages: response.items})` with the new messages after you've sent a message. How you're going to deal with messages from other users is a separate issue. See https://codeburst.io/polling-vs-sse-vs-websocket-how-to-choose-the-right-one-1859e4e13bd9 `setInterval` is one approach, but it's poor one. If you do need to poll, you should use `setTimeout` and schedule your next poll when the `setTimeout` handler runs to avoid `setInterval` handlers getting backed up if your window doesn't have focus. That's a separate topic though, read the link I sent

Comment: This appears to be a repost of your prior question: [Update data display without refreshing React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60925328/update-data-display-without-refreshing-react)